# Adding Items From Listbox to List

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

A simple, rather open ended question. I am wanting to add all items in a **Listbox** to an object, to later print that those items into a database. Is the best practice for adding all items in a **Listbox** to an array?

Thanks

Comment: a ListBox can contain Object, not just strings.  Easiest thing is to put the data in a List(of String) to start with, then set the list as the listbox datasource.  No need to copy or transfer the data

Comment: Is that an option for asp.net web forms? I feel like I have tried that and it was out of scope for web forms.

Comment: What kind of ListBox at all, winforms or webforms? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've commented that you are using ASP.NET, you can use a loop:

```
Dim allListBoxItemsText = New List(Of String) 
For Each item As ListItem In listBox1.Items
    allListBoxItemsText.Add(item.Text)
Next
```

or LINQ:

```
Dim items = From item In listBox1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)()
            Select item.Text
allListBoxItemsText = items.ToList() ' if you want an array use ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Id use the standard declare an array and loop through it. I am sure there is a more elegant solution but it works.

```
 Dim array(listbox1.items.count-1) As String
 Dim i as integer = 0

    For i = 0 to listbox1.items.count -1 
         array(i) = listbox1.items(i)
    Next
```